# IOS : Best practices for Fields Validation on User Interface

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, design-patterns, design-principles

In my app I want to validate `user inputs` in the fields. For Example

> If textfields is empty. Or email is in correct format

I don't want to add validation logic in **ViewController**, Neither I want to pass UIView  to a **Validator** Class

I have multiple screens like this.

Any suggestion for best ways validating Screens.

Comment: I would create a validator class for every field. and pass either the string from the field or the field self. Why don't you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting it for multiple scenes then it is good to have a validator class for all your `UITextFields`. I have written a [UITextField validator](https://github.com/anukooll/TextFieldValidator)  class which is very simple to use. You can modify it as you want. Take a look. Best luck

Comment: Only this class will be enough. All you have to do is just put this class as your all textField's superclass.

Answer (score 2):

what you can do is create `category` class of `UIView` and write instance method like

**Validation+UIView**

```
+(BOOL)isEmpty:(NSString *)string{
    // snippet to check empty validation and return value.
    }


+(BOOL)emailValidation:(NSString *)string{
// snippet to check email validation and return value.

}
```

Now use this instance method  on your view.

```
if(![yourview isEmpty]){
// all good ...
}
```

Comment: Its better to add category in UITextField.Rather then in UIView. My guess

Comment: yes it is but by using UIView he can also check validation for  UITextView as because he want validation globally.

Comment: Creating a category for validation (better). Thanks